# Stop jittering on position:fixed; elements across mobile devices when scrolling

Tags: android, html, css, iphone, mobile

We have an ad stuck to the bottom of the browser using `position:fixed`.

This works expected with Chrome/Firefox browsers.  When loaded on some mobiles (nearly all androids, old iPhones and most window phones) the ad moves - we can make this less janky with some css animation but its still not ideal.

[A simple fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/9dh6toun/).  It does seem to have be worse on content heavy pages.

Answer (score 3):

Managed to sort it out by hardware accelerating the container.

I used `transform: translateZ(0);` within the class setting the fixed position.